# How can I set \l_file_search_path_seq so \file_input:n finds files in Texlive 2019 as it did in Texlive 2018?

Tags: errors, expl3, external-files, documentclass-writing, texlive-2019

I have code which used to use `\file_path_include:n`, but now tries to adjust `\l_file_search_path_seq` as follows. With Texlive 2018, this works, but with Texlive 2019, it doesn't. What am I missing?

Working directory contains a subdirectory `abc`.
Directory `abc` contains a file named `a.tex` with the contents

```
hylo
```

The main file in the working directory contains:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_file_search_path_seq {abc}
\seq_show:N \l_file_search_path_seq
\file_input:n {a}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

This generates an error.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./prawf.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
) (./prawf.aux)
The sequence \l_file_search_path_seq contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {abc}.
<recently read> }

l.14 \seq_show:N \l_file_search_path_seq

? 

! LaTeX3 Error: File 'a' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.15 \file_input:n {a}

?
```

The same is true if I use `a.tex` in place of `a`, but the documentation for `\file_input:n` says it uses the same search as `\file_if_exist:n`, which searches the standard input path plus additions in `\l_file_search_path_seq`.

If I include the trailing forward slash when specifying the directory

```
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_file_search_path_seq {abc/}
```

as suggested by AlexWatson in a comment, I get errors but the file is eventually found.

```
! Argument of \__file_file_name_cleanup:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.17 \file_input:n {a.tex}

? 
Runaway argument?
\cs_if_exist:NT \input@path {\tl_map_tokens:Nn \input@path {\__file_full_name_a
ux:nn \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \__file_file_name_cleanup:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.17 \file_input:n {a.tex}

? 
(./abc/a.tex)
```

How can I set `\l_file_search_path_seq` correctly so that `\file_input:n` behaves as I want it to? Or, if that's not possible, what workarounds are available?

Comment: With such sincerity I wish you my welcome back to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you.

Comment: I can't test this as I don't have TL 2019 here, but is it possible that you need "abc/" instead of "abc"? This is how it works with `\input@path`, which the l3file documentation suggests that this mimics/replaces.

Comment: @AlexWatson The documentation says `Each
path can be relative or absolute, and should not include the trailing slash.` I assumed that meant I ought not to include it.

Comment: @AlexWatson You are onto something. I get horrible errors, but it eventually finds the file. See edit above.

Comment: Most likely there's a bug in the reworked code here: I'll check probably tomorrow

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you so much. I was sure I was doing something idiotic. (I reverted to 2018 to get stuff processed, where I can use `\l_file_search_path_seq` or `\file_path_include:n`. You can't tell me what `\l__file_base_name_str` is now, can you? My tikz externalisation fails, too.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99249/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-cfr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in some new code: we have work on the go for an expandable `\file_input:n`, and the first step was file searching. Things are fixed as described in https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/634: an update will go to CTAN probably tomorrow.